# Slow CSS3 transitions on Android 4.4 vs iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css

I am using keyframe based CSS3 animations to slide between divs with a bezier curve of (.10,.70,.10,1) with a duration of 400 ms

Performance on Android (tested on a HTC One M8 and S4 using both the native 4.4 web view and the blink based Crosswalk) is extremely janky and stuttery with a very poor frame rate. Performance on iOS from the 4s through to the 5s is perfect with near native performance.

Can someone please explain what might cause this and some suggestions on how to correct it, would it require using a javascript based animation solution like VelocityJS?

Apologies if the question is a touch vague but i dont think my adding reams of CSS keyframe rules to this question will help anyone so i am omitting it.

Here is a stripped down example which demonstrates what i am talking about

http://jsfiddle.net/hu69H/

(works fine on desktop but not perfectly and bar iOS its not performant on mobile at all)

Here is a snippet of the code which does the logical portion of the sliding:

```
var $ = function (id) {
        "use strict";
        return document.getElementById(id);
    },
    slideOpts = {
        sl: ['slin', 'slout'],
        sr: ['srin', 'srout'],
        popin: ['popin', 'noanim'],
        popout: ['noanim', 'popout'],
        noanim: ['noanim', 'noanim']
    },

function Slide(slideType, vin, vout, callback) {
    var vIn = $(vin),
        vOut = $(vout),
        onAnimationEnd = function () {
            vOut.classList.add('hidden');
            vIn.classList.remove(slideOpts[slideType][0]);
            vOut.classList.remove(slideOpts[slideType][1]);
            vOut.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', onAnimationEnd, false);
            vOut.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
        };

    if (slideType == 'noanim'){
        vIn.classList.remove('hidden');
        vOut.classList.add('hidden');

    } else {
        vOut.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', onAnimationEnd, false);
        vOut.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
        if (callback && typeof (callback) === 'function') {
            callback();
        }
        vIn.classList.remove('hidden');
        vIn.classList.add(slideOpts[slideType][0]);
        vOut.classList.add(slideOpts[slideType][1]);
    }
```

Comment: Probably because iOS has hardware acceleration and Android does not. Not sure though.

Comment: Is it only with this animation? Did you try using the stock ease transition?  If the stock works you could use a media query to use that on mobile.

Comment: Given the fact im getting no reply since adding my code, ill just post my findings. Box shadows where used to add depth to the transition and make it more true to an iOS page swap animation. Box shadow is extremely heavy and is slow on the iPhone 4 and almost unusable on Android but works perfectly from the 4s through to the 5s. If anyone could suggest a more performant way of adding and removing classes and or a smoother curve id be very grateful.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 can you reference any post from Android stating this? we are also running into the same problem and worst case scenario, we need to explain it to the client. Any reference would be welcomed.

Comment: @JamesWong Just so you know you historically had to manually enable hardware acceleration in the AndroidManifest.xml, as of 4.1 (i think) this is the default, to achieve the best results across all platforms please see:  https://www.crosswalk-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

do you have a sample case to reproduce this?  This will help a lot to identify the root cause..

Comment: Modified my question with a JSFiddle Link to show a real world example as well as a snippet of the code to keep SO happy.